# Can Android Activities live without Layout Files

Tags: android, android-activity

Can an Activity live without a Layout file? Apparently yes, but how are activities attached to layouts?

Comment: your ui is drawn on the screen. What do you mean by activities attached to layouts?

Comment: by using setContentView()

Comment: by attached i mean, how are they referenced to each other, how does android know which activity goes with which layout?

Comment: @AnandSingh can you give an example how you would do stuff like adding widgets or defining layouts?

Comment: @user1767754 look into the source cod of activity http://androidxref.com/5.1.1_r6/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/Activity.java

Comment: setContentView(R.layout.activity_main).... this will define which layout is attached with your activity.

Comment: @Raghunandan this source code is for experts like you :D

Comment: @user1767754 see the example i shared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html), an Activity can create a view in two ways.

1. Declare UI elements in XML. Android provides a straightforward XML vocabulary that corresponds to the View classes and subclasses, such as those for widgets and layouts.
2. Instantiate layout elements at runtime. Your application can create View and ViewGroup objects (and manipulate their properties) programmatically.

> When you compile your application, each XML layout file is compiled
>   into a View resource. You should load the layout resource from your
>   application code, in your `Activity.onCreate()` callback implementation.
>   Do so by calling `setContentView()`, passing it the reference to your
>   layout resource in the form of: `R.layout.layout_file_name`. For
>   example, if your XML layout is saved as `main_layout.xml`, you would
>   load it for your Activity like so:
>
> ```
> public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>     setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);
> }
> ```

Answer (score 2):

See this code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); // Here you are defining which layout is attached
                                                // with this activity class

    }
}
```

So there is one layout file named `activity_main.xml` inside `res/layout` folder.

So in method `setContentView` we pass parameter `Layout Resource`. This will attach `layout` to `activity` class.

This is code of `setContentView` method. You can see here we pass `layoutResID` as parameter.

```
public void setContentView(int layoutResID) {
        getWindow().setContentView(layoutResID);
        initWindowDecorActionBar();
    }
```

So in my above code `R.layout.activity_main` is `layoutResID` of `activity_main.xml` layout file.

Answer (score 1):

Layout file is not necessary. You can do something like this (show a button on screen without layout file):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
            Button button = new Button(this);
            button.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            button.setText("This is a button");
            linearLayout.addView(button);
            addContentView(linearLayout, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code in the `onCreate()` method of the activity:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
```

Importance of the `layout.xml`:

You can declare your application's default layouts in XML, including the screen elements that will appear in them and their properties. The, you can add code in your application that can modify the state of the screen objects, including those declared in XML, at the run time.

> It enables you to better separate the presentation of your application from the code that controls its behavior. Your UI specifications are external to your application logic, which means that modification of the XML is sufficient without having to alter your application code and recompile it again.

Answer (score 0):

See below code:

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Set the user interface layout for this Activity
    // The layout file is defined in the project res/layout/main_activity.xml file
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
}
```